# Out Parameters in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's think that a stored procedure takes an out parameter. When this stored procedure is called with this out parameter is already initialized to something, does this situation cause an exception? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't cause an error if you pass in a value to the output parameter - it's perfectly valid to have an input/output parameter which is what that would be.